# Close reason for medical advice questions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderation, close-reasons

It sometimes happens that people mistake Skeptics for a medical forum, and ask medical advice.

While this doesn't happen that often, if we had a custom reason, we could make sure all these questions are closed with the same advice, along the lines of:

> This question is about medical advice.
>
> We are not doctors. Don't ask for medical advice on line. Consult your
> physician.

Or something similar.

Is this a good idea? What would be an appropriate text to use?

Comment: [Biology's close reason, for reference](https://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/706/including-health-advice-in-the-personal-medical-questions-off-topic-reason): "Personal medical questions and health advice are off-topic on Biology. We can not safely answer questions for your specific situation and you should always consult a doctor for medical advice." That's only for personal medical advice, though.

Comment: @HDE226868 let's try it.

Comment: Ah, I see it's been put into action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Biology's close reason](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/706/including-health-advice-in-the-personal-medical-questions-off-topic-reason) was first used on Skeptics [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/26974/does-the-tumor-like-enlargement-of-penis-dangerous):

> Personal medical questions and health advice are off-topic on Skeptics. We can not safely answer questions for your specific situation and you should always consult a doctor for medical advice."

I think that works nicely. In addition, the reason

> "This question doesn't identify a specific notable claim. Please add a reference to and quote from the published text which contains the specific claim you want to question."

was used by the other close voters. But I think the medical advice reason works better.

Anyway, this post is for voting on the suggestion of the wording used in that question.

---

Also, perhaps this could be worked into the [medical-science](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medical-science) tag, though I don't know if that's been an issue before.